# Printing variable headers

Tags: python

I want to print these headers to get longer/shorter when the length of the string changes. I have no real idea how I would do this, I thought I could use len() and print a number of "=" depending on the length of them but it didn't turn out as expected.

```
+==========================+
| Running: hba_test
| Skipping: abort/"Basic Sanity" delayedabort/"Abort Control List"
+==========================+
+==========================+
| Skipping: sdt_test
+==========================+
```

These are the headers and this is the code used to generate them currently.

```
    #print header to seperate tests
    l1 = len(x)
    l2 = len(y)

    print "+==========================+"
    if disable:
        print "| Skipping: %s " % x
    else:
        print "| Running: %s " % x
        if 'disable=' in test:
           print "| Skipping:%s " % y 
    print "+==========================+"
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't turn out expected"; what code did you use, what did you expect, and what did you actually get?

Comment: Why not use colors instead of ascii art? That way you avoid having to care about the length altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something along these lines? It is not elegant and "hard coded" though.

### Using your original code:

```
x = 'hba_test'
y = 'abort/"Basic Sanity" delayedabort/"Abort Control List"'
disable = False
test = 'disable='

#print header to seperate tests
l1 = len(x)
l2 = len(y)


if disable:
    headerBreak ="+" + "="*(l1+12) + "+"
    print headerBreak
    print "| Skipping: %s |" % x
else:
    headerBreak =  "+" + "="*(max(l1,l2)+11) + "+"
    print headerBreak
    print "| Running: %s" % x, ' '*(l2-l1)+ '|'
    if 'disable=' in test:
       print "| Skipping:%s |" % y 
print headerBreak
```

Returns:

```
+=================================================================+
| Running: hba_test                                               |
| Skipping:abort/"Basic Sanity" delayedabort/"Abort Control List" |
+=================================================================+

+====================+
| Skipping: hba_test |
+====================+
```

---

### Using a Function:

```
x = 'hba_test'
y = 'abort/"Basic Sanity" delayedabort/"Abort Control List"'
disable = False
test = 'disable='

#print header to seperate tests
def asciiBlock(lineList):
    maxLength = 0
    lines = []
    for line in lineList:
        newLine = ': '.join(line)
        lines.append(newLine)
        if maxLength<len(newLine):
            maxLength=len(newLine)


    asciiArt = '+'+'='*(maxLength+2)+'+'
    newLineList = [asciiArt]
    for line in lines:
        newLineList.append('| '+ line + ' '*(maxLength-len(line))+' |')

    newLineList.append(asciiArt)

    return '\n'.join(newLineList)


if disable:
    lineList = [('Skipping',x)]

else:
    lineList = [('Running',x)]
    if 'disable=' in test:
        lineList.append(('Skipping',y))

print asciiBlock(lineList)
```

Comment: @AlanGordon I added a more robust solution using a function.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

If you know how many `=`s you'd like to print, you can do the following:

```
In [2]: "=" * 50
Out[2]: '=================================================='
```